# 404 not found after deploying laravel 5.3 into AWS EC2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-ec2, laravel-5.3

I deployed (actually cloned from git my site, previously developed on local server) into AWS EC2 instance. I did the necessary things like composer updating, .env file etc. But still it is showing 404 error when I try to visit my site --

```
{my-public-ip}/{my-site}/public/
```

what am I missing here?

Comment: Are you using Apache or Nginx (or something else)?

Comment: I am using apache 2.4 .

Answer (score 0):

I ran sudo a2enmod rewrite and for some unknown reason, it worked. Strange! No idea what or how this happened

Comment: Laravel makes use apache's mod rewrite for its routing. I would imagine that AWS doesn't set this up as default.